# Connect to db inside docker failed

Tags: mysql, docker

I am running my application in a environment like below:

- The `app_runner` image creates the database and runs the application.
- The `test_runner` image is `FROM app_runner`, connects to the database in the first container, and connects to the application.
- Machine 1 runs `app_runner`.
- Machine 2 runs `test_runner`.

When I run this the container on Machine 2 successfully connects to the application, but can't connect to the database.

**runner.df**

```
WORKDIR /opt/user/application
COPY *.sql ./
COPY app.tgz ./
EXPOSE 4210
EXPOSE 3306
RUN tar xzf app.tgz
mysql -hlocalhost -uroot --port=3306 < create_schema.sql
mysql -hlocalhost -uroot --port=3306 < create_data.sql
cd app/
./bin/app_name
```

**test_runner.df**

```
FROM app_runner:latest
WORKDIR /opt/user/app
COPY automated_tests/ .
CMD pybot ./Tests
```

Machine 1:

```
docker build --tag app_runner:latest -f runner.df .
docker run -p 4210:4210 -p 3306:3306 -itd app_runner:latest
```

Machine 2:

```
docker build --tag test_runner:latest -f test_runner.df .
docker run -it test_runer:latest
```

Gives error:

> OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '10.113.10.28' (111)")

where 10.113.10.28 is Machine 1's IP address.

Comment: attach all docker files or commands and errors

Comment: provide Dockerfile or relevant code, it is self explaining to pros!

Comment: Yeah, give us all the errors!
Could be as simple as you not exposing the ports on the containers, the ports being used on the host, the ports not being exposed on the hosts or a combination of them all..

Answer (score 0):

Your first image isn't starting the MySQL database; the only thing it's starting is the main application.  I'm guessing you have MySQL installed, but it doesn't start up when you launch the container.

You should probably split the application and database into separate containers.  Use the standard `mysql` image for the database.  It has a path to run SQL files on first startup to prepopulate the database.  The application image needs to be given a pointer to the database location; if you already have a multi-host setup then passing in an environment variable with the host's IP address might be the simplest setup.